# Lambda functions python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I got the following code:

```
g = lambda x: x+7
foo = lambda f: (lambda x: f(x+1)*2)
print( g(3), (foo(g))(3), (foo(foo(g))((3) )
```

Could I get an explanation on how `(foo(foo(g))((3)` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to remember is that `lambda`s are regular functions that:

1. Don't automatically have names
2. Can be used as expressions
3. Must consist of a single expression
4. Implicitly `return` the results of that expression

So you can always rewrite them as normal `def` functions with names if you're confused. For example, `foo` can become:

```
def foo(f):
    def foo_inner(x):
        return f(x + 1) * 2
    return foo_inner
```

So calling `foo` with any function (`f`) returns a new function which takes a numeric type, adds one to it, calls `f` with the value, and doubles the result.

All the rest of it is just tracing the multiple layers of wrapping here, which I'll leave to you; this isn't an interesting problem in general. In real code that uses factory functions like this, the intent and behavior is generally much more clear (because it's being done for a purpose, rather than as a brainteaser).